# Как обновить блок через JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть обычный блок, в котором расположены несколько вложенных блоков. Мне этот блок нужно обновить через jQuery. Не надо заменять другим контентом, типа $('#block').html(html). Просто этот блок обновить и все

Comment: что ты вкладываешь в понятие "обновить"?

Comment: То есть вы хотите заменить innerHTML у блока?

Comment: Нет, это как обычное обновление страницы

Comment: Но вот только без явной перезагрузки

Comment: Ты непонятно выражаешься. Ты что-то туда добавлять хочешь? или зачем обновлять блок?

Comment: Запрашиваете у сервера код блока через `$.ajax` и вставляете через `el.html`.

Comment: У меня есть сессия, которая выводит товары. После добавления нового товара блок не обновляется и там появится новый товар только тогда, когда страница или блок будет обновлен

Comment: Да, тоже думал через ajax, но как реализовать в JS, я не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: @user207012 то есть по факту тебе нужно принять данные с сервера и сделать `append`.

Comment: Да, скорее всего так и надо сделать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `append` добавит, а не заменит старые блок.

Comment: Вот только из сессии надо взять данные в JS и уже с помощью append добавить вложенный блок

Comment: Хотя на самом деле проще перерисовать блок. Т.к. логика добавления и удаления требует слегка разного поведения и рисовать лишнюю логику - лишне.

Comment: Вот-вот, я неправильно изначально выразился, да, мне надо перерисовать блок

Comment: Ну так что, вы сможете помочь?)